# Distribution of forecast error of ARMA + GARCH model

Tags: distributions, forecasting, arima, garch

I am modelling a time series process and want to explore ARMA + GARCH.
Using ARMA alone, with normally distributed residuals, we can determine the distribution of the forecast error using the technique [described here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/3/3.3#paragraph--289). This involves converting the ARMA to a pure MA representation and multiplying the model variance by a factor derived from the pure MA representation.

$$\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{forecast} = \hat{\sigma}^2_{model}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\Psi^2_j$$ where each $\Psi_j$ 
 comes from the pure MA representation.

1. If I am using GARCH with a normal distribution, and thus have a
   different forecast for variance for each day out to $m$, can I
   simply do this?

$$\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{forecast} = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\hat{\sigma}^2_{garch,j}\Psi^2_j$$

2. If I am using GARCH with a skew t distribution (or any of those
   offered by `rugarch` in R), is it known how to combine each of these
   single period distributions into a distribution for the whole
   forecast horizon? In the normal case it is simple, since a normal
   distribution is completely characterized by it's mean (from ARMA)
   and variance (from GARCH). But for a skew t, I am not certain if
   this is valid to keep skew and shape constant and just adjust scale using the above procedure.

Comment: Regarding 2, the formula for variance of a sum of random variables applies regardless of the distributions of the random variables, as long as the variance is finite.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy, the question was more about how to describe the distribution in full. As I mentioned, a normal distribution is characterized by mean and variance, both of which can be forecast. So by knowing mean and variance, I everything I need for a normal distribution. Skew t on the other hand, not so clear to me. `rugarch` gives me a forcast of the scale parameter for a skew t distribution. So the obvious idea is to run the same idea for a normal distribution, but just keep the shape and skew parameters constant. However the central limit theorem must kick in as we push out horizon.

Comment: OK, I got you..